# Does the work function of metal depend upon the intensity of light?

Tags: photons

does work function of metal depend upon the intensity of light?or does it depend upon the nature of metal?And according to my perception its depend upon both intensity and nature of light.

Answer (score 4):

The work function is the difference between the energy of the most excited electrons in the conduction band and the vacuum. It's the energy required to take an electron from the conduction band and remove it to outside the metal.

To a first approximation the work function is independant of the intensity of the light, because it's an intrinsic property of the metal. However in practice there may be very small side effects e.g. if the light heats the metal surface this will reduce the work function very slightly.

Comment: John, I have a question for my own curiosity sake (it's related to the OP, but probably not worth a new question on Stack).  What happens if you supply a large enough photon intensity to sublimate the metal but keep the gas in the same physical volume?  Does its phase transition to gaseous form render it no longer a conductor and thus eliminating the issue of the work function?

Comment: @honeste_vivere: a dilute metal gas won't conduct electricity and will not have a work function. The atoms will have an ionisation energy, but the ionisation energy of atoms is typically around 5eV or a factor of 2 - 3 times greater than the work function of metals.

Comment: Ah, I see.  That is neat that by existing in a metal lattice, the properties of the electrons' mobility and motion are fundamentally different from that of a conducting gas...  (Solid-State and Condensed Matter always confused me in grad school)

Answer (score 1):

As amplification:

The emission of photo-electrons is a quantum effect:  one electron receives the energy from a single photon.  If the energy of that photon, proportional to its frequency, is sufficient to overcome the work function, then photo-electrons will be produced.  If the frequency is too low, then no photo-electrons will be produced.  **Increasing the intensity of the same frequency of light only increases the number of photons, not their individual energy.**  More photons, each without enough energy, will never create any photo-electrons

An important experiment in early quantum physics involved shining a faint light on a photo-emissive surface for a **very** short period of time.  The frequency of the light was high enough to produce photo-electrons.  The intensity and time were such that there was no way for the surface to receive enough energy during the short exposure to produce a photo-electron.  But, experimentally, a small number of these exposures **did** produce photo-electrons.  The conclusion was that the energy flow was not a weak, continuous flow, but rather the infrequent passing of high-energy "lumps" or photons...